# com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate symbol not found after upgrading to Spring boot 1.4.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I just updated the spring boot version to 1.4.0. After that I am getting errors like

```
Error:(109, 45) java: no suitable method found for findAll(com.mysema.query.types.Predicate,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
    method org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.Predicate cannot be converted to com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate)
    method org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.Predicate cannot be converted to com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate)
    method org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.Predicate cannot be converted to com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>)
    method org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.Predicate cannot be converted to com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate)
```

Prior to upgrading, the queries were working properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely (since the info provided is very limited) you're on the wrong version of QueryDSL. QueryDSL Predicate class is now (as of QueryDSL 4) in the package `com.querydsl.core.types`.
Try dropping the version of your queryDSL dependencies from your pom (if using maven) and use Spring Boot BOM dependency in the dependency management section instead. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)

Comment: I am using gradle for managing dependencies, with hibernate version  = 5.2.1.FINAL and springboot version 1.4.0.RELEASE. How to use springboot BOM dependency in gradle?

Comment: the artefact group has changed to `com.querydsl`